# Firestore collectionGroup query returns empty result

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

My Firestore database is currently set up as such:
[image: Database]

Groups have members (list of users) and I want to query and find all the groups a specific user. I found the collectionGroup query should be the solution and here is my code for the query.

```
let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let ref = db.collectionGroup("members").whereField("id", isEqualTo: userID)
    ref.getDocuments(completion: { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else { return }
        print(snapshot.documents.count) --> Always 0
    })
```

I followed the documentation and added index in the database:
[image]

And also updated the security rules (app is not public yet so the rules are just placeholder).

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write;
  }
  match /{path=**}/members/{doc} {
      allow read, write;
  }
  }
}
```

Need help understanding why (and fix) the query always return empty result when clearly the database has a group with a member with the matching userID.

Comment: please refer a document again, use case for collectionGroup is different from the way you are trying to achieve.
As the name suggest itself it query ref should have "collection" grouped

Answer (score 2):

> the query always return empty result when clearly the database has a group with a member with the matching userID.

This is happening because `member` is a property within your document and **not** a subcollection.

According to the official documentation regarding [collection group queries in Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query):

> A collection group consists of all collections with the same ID. By default, queries retrieve results from a single collection in your database. Use a collection group query to retrieve documents from a collection group instead of from a single collection.

So if you want to use collection group queries, you need to change the `member` property into a subcollection, where you should add `member` objects and only then your query will work.

Before using a collection group query, don't also forget to create an index that supports your collection group query.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the members as a map type in a field but in a collection.

You will then get an error in your console with a link for creating the index you want like this:

> The query requires a COLLECTION_GROUP_ASC index for collection
>   members and field id. You can create it here:
>   https://console.firebase.google...

Give it a little time before the new index is effective.